# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component, when using no async effects in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting an error in my React application.

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
>
> in LayoutLogin (at AppContent.js:22)
>
> in Route (at AppContent.js:22)

From what I can tell, it's because the component `LayoutLogin` is getting unmounted once it sees that you are authenticated and redirects you to the page you should be going to.  But I don't know how to fix it, as I don't see any async functions being called, which is what everything I've been searching is used as an example of how to fix.  So how am I supposed to stop this memory leak?

`AppContent.js`

```
export default function AppContent() {
    const [settings] = useGlobal('settings');

    return (
        <Switch>
            {settings.guestEnabled && <Route exact path="/"><LayoutDash/></Route>}
            {!settings.guestEnabled && <PrivateRoute exact path="/"><LayoutDash/></PrivateRoute>}
            {settings.registrationEnabled && <Route exact path="/register"><LayoutRegister/></Route>}
            <PrivateRoute path="/options"><LayoutOptions/></PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute path="/settings"><LayoutSettings/></PrivateRoute>
            <Route exact path="/login"><LayoutLogin/></Route>  // Line 22
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

`LayoutLogin.js`

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import LayoutBase from "./LayoutBase";
import {useDispatch, useGlobal} from 'reactn';
import {useAPI} from "../hooks/useAPI";
import {useHistory, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

export default function LayoutLogin() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [isAuthenticated] = useGlobal('isAuthenticated');
    const [options] = useGlobal('options');
    const authError = useDispatch('authError');
    const authSuccess = useDispatch('authSuccess');
    const fetchToken = useAPI('/api/auth/token/obtain/');


    const [login, setLogin] = React.useState({
        username: '',
        password: '',
    });
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = React.useState(false);

    const history = useHistory();
    const location = useLocation();
    let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };

    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = `Login | ${options.appName}`;
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            history.replace(from);
        }
    }, [isAuthenticated, options]);

    // Handle state change from form elements
    const handleLoginChange = option => event => {
        setLogin({
            ...login,
            [option]: event.target.value,
        });
    };

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        // submit form here
    };

    return (
        <LayoutBase>
            // Login form components here
        </LayoutBase>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has less to do with LayoutLogin and more to do with the conditional rendering of the routes in AppContent. LayoutLogin doesn't appear to be unmounted in the code that you've provided. AFAIK, React doesn't unmount an element if it is an unconditional child of another unconditional element. It may not be asked to rerender, but it's still in the tree.

The top Route and PrivateRoute objects, however, are conditionally rendered, and will mount/unmount when those conditions are true/false. I've never seen this pattern before, and it feels like an anti-pattern. Typically routes are defined, then their contents decide if they should render a valid result or an error, based upon state available to the contents.

The only way I can see LayoutLogin causing problems is if one of its hooks isn't cleaning up after itself.